# Multiple IP's with tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

i'm french and I have a question.

Bonjour, j'aimerai utiliser plusieurs IP's en même temps avec Tor, j'ai vu que c'était possible mais je n'arrive toujours pas : je n'ai pas bien compris le changement de port/control port ect... Pouvez-vous m'aider ?

Hello, i'd like to use more than one ip with tor browsers, i know it's possible but i'm bad, i dont enderstand the "control port" ect... can you help me ?

Thanks, merci

## AFrenchWhoNeedHelp

Answer (score 0):

You need no ControlPort tricks but a SOCKS proxy endpoint authentication. The thing is that multiple sessions to a single Tor instance using different login+password pairs will use different circuits, i.e. external IP's.

Take a look at [the official docs cite](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) :

> **SocksPort [address:]port|unix:path|auto [flags] [*isolation flags*]**
>   Open this port to listen for connections from SOCKS-speaking applications. Set this to 0 if you don’t want to allow application connections via SOCKS. Set it to "auto" to have Tor pick a port for you. This directive can be specified multiple times to bind to multiple addresses/ports. (Default: 9050)
>
> NOTE: Although this option allows you to specify an IP address other than localhost, you should do so only with extreme caution. The SOCKS protocol is unencrypted and (as we use it) unauthenticated, so exposing it in this way could leak your information to anybody watching your network, and allow anybody to use your computer as an open proxy.
>
> The isolation flags arguments give Tor rules for which streams received on this SocksPort are allowed to share circuits with one another. Recognized isolation flags are:
>
> **IsolateClientAddr**
>   Don’t share circuits with streams from a different client address. (On by default and strongly recommended; you can disable it with NoIsolateClientAddr.)
>
> **IsolateSOCKSAuth**
>   Don’t share circuits with streams for which different SOCKS authentication was provided. (On by default; you can disable it with NoIsolateSOCKSAuth.)
>
> **IsolateClientProtocol**
>   Don’t share circuits with streams using a different protocol. (SOCKS 4, SOCKS 5, TransPort connections, NATDPort connections, and DNSPort requests are all considered to be different protocols.)
>
> **IsolateDestPort**
>   Don’t share circuits with streams targeting a different destination port.
>
> **IsolateDestAddr**
>   Don’t share circuits with streams targeting a different destination address.